# Retrieving Null text in socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am sending data from the client to the server. I am retrieving the data from the client and storing it in variable and calling a function, but when I run the program I get null value in the output.
The following output is received

```
 Received b''
```

I want the string to be printed with the string too. Thanks
import socket

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)


def ceaser(data):
 shift = 3  # defining the shift count

 encrypted_text = data
 plain_text = ""
 for c in encrypted_text:

    # check if character is an uppercase letter
    if c.isupper():
        # find the position in 0-25
        c_unicode = ord(c)
        c_index = ord(c) - ord("A")
        # perform the negative shift
        new_index = (c_index - shift) % 26
        # convert to new character
        new_unicode = new_index + ord("A")
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        # append to plain string
        plain_text = plain_text + new_character
        return plain_text
    else:

        # since character is not uppercase, leave it as it is
        plain_text += c
    return plain_text

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.bind((HOST, PORT))
  s.listen()
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  with conn:
    print('Connected by', addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data=ceaser(data)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)
```

#client side

```
 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
   s.connect((HOST, PORT))
   s.sendall(b'KHOOR ZRUOG')
   data = s.recv(1024)
   print('Received', repr(data))
```

Comment: In Python there is no Null value. What do your server and client print? Please copy-paste.

Comment: You should use str or bytes consistently, but not both. To use bytes, do plain_text = b""

Answer (score 0):

While the direct cause of this would be tedious to figure out, I do recommend developing some kind of protocol to use, even just a basic one. With that I mean first sending information about the comming message, like the amount of bytes it contains. This information would be kept in a packet of fixed length, by padding it with null bytes. That way you first read a packet of size, say, 512. Then you decode that and know the size of the comming message, and can adjust your `recv()` to accept that amount of bytes.

Another thing to keep in mind is the encoding of the message. It is a good habbit to use a str when handling the message, but when sending and recieving, using .decode() and .encode() to convert it to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct code. This works fine now.

**Server**

```py
import socket
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)


def ceaser(data):
    shift = 3  # defining the shift count

    encrypted_text = data.decode('utf-8')
    plain_text = ""
    for c in encrypted_text:
        # check if character is an uppercase letter
        if c.isupper():
            # find the position in 0-25
            c_unicode = ord(c)
            c_index = ord(c) - ord("A")
            # perform the negative shift
            new_index = (c_index - shift) % 26
            # convert to new character
            new_unicode = new_index + ord("A")
            new_character = chr(new_unicode)
            # append to plain string
            plain_text = plain_text + new_character
            #return plain_text
        else:
            # since character is not uppercase, leave it as it is
            plain_text += c
    return plain_text

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            data=ceaser(data)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

**Client**

```py
import socket
HOST = '127.0.0.1' 
PORT = 65432
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
   s.connect((HOST, PORT))
   s.sendall(b'KHOOR ZRUOG')
   data = s.recv(1024)
   print('Received', repr(data))
```

**What is the issue?**

- You have to decode when received before decrypt and encode before sending after decryption. at line 6 and last line of Server.
- You need to take the return statement outside of for loop in caeser function